# Solid Principles / Builder Pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, interface, .net-core, solid-principles

I am creating a very small application to demonstrate solid principles and also a brief implementation of a builder pattern, does anyone have any feedback as to how this could be improved or how it breaks the solid principles? The app is a small app that just converts units, e.g. yards to meters, inches to cms.

**Interface**

```
public interface IConverter
{
    double ConversionRate { get; set; }
    string[] ConvertedUnits { get; set; }
    string DisplayText { get; set; }

    string[] Convert(string input);
}
```

**Class implementing interface**

```
 public class Converter : IConverter
    {
        public double ConversionRate { get; set; }
        public string[] ConvertedUnits { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }

        public Converter(double conversionRate, string[] convertedUnits, string displayText)
        {
            ConversionRate = conversionRate;
            ConvertedUnits = convertedUnits;
            DisplayText = displayText;
        }

        public string[] Convert(string input)
        {
            if (!input.Contains('\n'))
            {
                double d = double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * ConversionRate;

                string[] array = new string[1];
                array[0] = d.ToString();

                return array;
            }
            else
            {
                double[] doubles = new double[input.Split('\n').Count()];

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Split('\n').Count(); i++)
                {
                    double value = double.Parse(input.Split('\n')[i]);
                    doubles[i] = value;

                    string.Format("{0}", value * ConversionRate);
                }

                string[] strings = new string[doubles.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Split('\n').Length; i++)
                {
                    strings[i] = string.Format("{0}", doubles[i] * ConversionRate);
                }

                return strings;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Builder (abstract class)**

```
public abstract class ConverterBuilder
    {
        protected double _conversionRate;
        protected string[] _convertedUnits;
        protected string _displayText;

        public ConverterBuilder AddConversionRate(double conversionRate)
        {
            _conversionRate = conversionRate;
            return this;
        }

        public ConverterBuilder AddConversionRate(string[] convertedUnits)
        {
            _convertedUnits = convertedUnits;
            return this;
        }

        public ConverterBuilder AddDisplayText(string displayText)
        {
            _displayText = displayText;
            return this;
        }

        public Converter Build()
        {
            return new Converter(_conversionRate, _convertedUnits, _displayText);
        }

    }
```

**Builder implementing abstract builder class**

```
public class UnitConverterBuilder : ConverterBuilder
{
    public UnitConverterBuilder()
    {

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Convert(string text, double conversionRate)
{
    Converter converter = new UnitConverterBuilder()
    .AddConversionRate(conversionRate)
    .Build();

    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < converter.Convert(text).Count(); i++)
    {
        output += converter.Convert(text)[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    return Content(output);

}
```

**View**

Enter values to convert

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Convert" method="post">
    <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    <select name="conversionRate">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="0.9144">Yards to Meters</option>
        <option value="2.54">Inches To Centimeters</option>
    </select>
    <button>Convert</button>
</form>
```

The app is built using .net core, any feedback greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hmmm, here I would just have a single static UnitConverter class with an enumeration of supported units (NOT Strings) and built-in conversion rates. 
Also, your IConverter interface would appear to violate SOLID with its DisplayText function.

Comment: Thanks, on the display text violating SOLID, could you expand on that?

Comment: What does the DisplayText have to do with the converters job of converting? It violates the Single Responsibility Principle - now you are making it responsible for the UI.

Comment: Ahh yes very good point, so move display text to the class and remove from interface

Comment: If you use enums for the Units, the UI layer can grab those and convert those to strings. You can also add Description Attributes to the enum values if needed.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll give that a go

Comment: You converter violates SRP also because it's parsing the input string. Why not make it expect the actual value (numeric) to be converted!

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not necessarily related to SOLID principle but here are a few things I would mention if I was reviewing this code at work

- Excessive use of char `'/n'`. If you wanted to change from `'/n'` to `'/r/n'` you would have to change it 5 times in `Converter.Convert`. A better way to handle this would be to store this in a variable or perhaps allow it to be set via the constructor.
- You can use `var` instead of explicitly stating the variable type e.g `var d = double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * ConversionRate;`
- Variable names, clean code should be easy to read so rather than using names like d and doubles use names that are easy for someone reading the code to understand
- You don't need to specify the properties of Converter on the interface IConverter, this is because the interface only needs to expose the behaviors of the object and the properties are more of an implementation detail. Removing the properties will allow to you to have multiple objects that implement IConvert without being forced to have those specific properties (interface segregation)

I hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, looks like a copy and paste error... Your second AddConversionRate method should be AddConversionUnits.

Regarding the SOLID principles, you can't always show evidence of all the principles in a small code example like this.

1. Single responsibility - As mentioned the display text in the converter probably violates this principle.
2. Open/Closed - you are not extending any classes here so it is difficult to show with your example.
3. Liskov's Substitution - no subclasses so again no evidence of violation of this one.
4. Interface Segregation - DisplayText should be pulled out of IConverter.
5. Dependency Inversion - Biggest violations are here. Details are implemented against concrete types rather than abstractions. Build on ConverterBuilder should return an IConverter rather than a concrete Converter. Your controller Convert action should declare the converter variable as an IConverter rather than a Converter concrete type and I would also inject that dependency into the controller class in the constructor (again as an IConverter) then use that dependency in the action rather than declaring a local variable.

I've written [an article on the SOLID principles](https://medium.com/bgl-tech/what-are-the-solid-design-principles-c61feff33685) that you might find interesting